# Does Ionic2 has kinds of config like gulpStartupTasks in Ionic1's ionic.project file?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, gulp-watch

I just want to run `gulp watch` along with `ionic serve`. looking forward some help there. thanks..  ( all i want to do is not to open another bash window to run `gulp watch`)

Comment: Ionic2 is using different way to build app. My question is why you want gulp watch?

Comment: i am working on ionic1.x project built with gulp.  but my Ionic CLI had upgraded to the newest.. so. you know.. things happend

Comment: There's no gulp. There's webpack, you can add your own config. But by watch don't you just want to do ionic serve -l?

Comment: haha~ now that there is no gulp. there is no gulp task could run with `ionic serve`. for me . just to open another bash window and run  `gulp watch `. problem solved~

Comment: finally decided to migrate to ionic2. hope everything just fine~